# Java Regex Replace Namespace

Tags: java, regex, replace

New to Regex.

Can anyone tell me what the java regex replacement code is to replace the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com">   <m_control xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com"><control_timestamp>2014-09-30T14:39:05.6402</control_timestamp>........</message>
```

and make it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><message><control_timestamp>2014-09-30T14:39:05.6402</control_timestamp>........</message>
```

The namespaces may be in differnt postions each time

Comment: [this is a good link to learn about regex](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead here.

```
<message.*?(?=<control_timestamp)
```

Replace the matched characters with `<message>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA3pD7/1)

```
String src = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><message xmlns=\"http://www.origoservices.com\">   <m_control xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://www.origoservices.com\"><control_timestamp>2014-09-30T14:39:05.6402</control_timestamp>........</message>";
String out = src.replaceAll("<message.*?(?=<control_timestamp)", "<message>");
System.out.println(out);
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><message><control_timestamp>2014-09-30T14:39:05.6402</control_timestamp>........</message>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `"<message.*<control_timestamp>"` with `"<message><control_timestamp>"`. then your output is ready.